# Count co-occurrences between elements in one column based on second column, and count only if unequal in third column

Tags: r, merge, conditional-statements, cross-join

I want to count how often each pairwise combination of unique elements in column `c` in data frame `df` co-occurs on the elements of column `a`, but with the addition that co-occurrences are only counted if the respective values in column `b` are unequal, i.e., conditional on a non-match in column `b`

```
a <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4)
b <- c(1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,4)
c <- c(1,2,1,2,3,2,3,1,2,1,1,2,3,1,2,1,1,2,4,1) 

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c))
```

Without considering column `b` I could do the following to retain for each pair of elements of column `c`, on how many elements of `a` they co-occur

```
df <- unique(df[,c(1,3)])
df <- merge(df, df, by = "a")
df$count <- 1

df <- aggregate(count ~ ., df[, c(2:4)], sum)
df <- df[df$c.x != df$c.y,]
```

With the additional condition of a non-match in `b`, there is only one difference: elements 2 and 4 of column `c` both co-occur on element 4 of column `a`, but have the same value in `b` and should therefore not be counted to end up with:

```
c.x <- c(2,3,4,1,3,1,2,1)
c.y <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4)
count <- c(4,3,1,4,3,3,3,1)

result <- as.data.frame(cbind(c.x,c.y,count))
```

As the original data set is large (> 1,000,000 observations), I welcome fast solutions, i.e., without using loops or merges. Usually, I create co-occurrence matrices from three-column data frames using `sparseMatrix()`

Comment: Can you show your expected output.  Do you neeed `crossprod(table(df[c(1, 3)]))`

Comment: Please elaborate on what you want. As is, your question is a bit confusing

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I added the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure from your description if this is what you had in mind, nor how fast this would turn out to be, but here is an approach with `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)

split(df, c) %>%
  combn(2, simplify = F) %>%
  set_names(map(., ~ paste(names(.x), collapse = "_"))) %>%
  map_int(~ merge(.x[[1]], .x[[2]], by = NULL) %>%
            dplyr::filter(a.x == a.y && b.x != b.y) %>%
            nrow())
```

Returns:

```
1_2 1_3 1_4 2_3 2_4 3_4 
  0  27   0  21   0   0
```

```
# Data used:
df <- structure(list(a = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), b = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4), c = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```